# PHP Copy not working properly

Tags: php, copy, file-copying

I've tried using this code to copy a PHP file from one directory to another one:

```
<?php
copy(example.php, dir/new_name.php);
?>
```

But the code is not working properly.
It says "there is no file called **examplephp** in this directory. The dot(**.**) was just ignored by PHP.
And when I tried uploading a file called "examplephp" in the server, the copied **examplephp** in to the other directory as **new_namephp**.
The dot again got ignored.
I tried this code and uploaded example.php file on the server (removed examplephp file):

```
<?php
    copy('example.php', "dir/new_name.php");
    ?>
```

Then the script found the file called example.php(dot was not ignored) but at the copy step, it again ignored the dot and copied 'example.php' as new_namephp".
And when I tried this code:

```
<?php
    copy('example.php', "dir/$new_name.php");
    ?>
```

, The script found example.php but it didn't identified "dir/$new_name.php".
How to solve this?
I want file (with extension) to be copied to another directory of the server, with renaming to another name(with the extension). How to do that?
I found this code on PHP.net. but it's not working:

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

Then tried this from stack overflow:

```
copy('foo/test.php', 'bar/test.php');
```

But still not working.

```
This question is solved. The problem was on the folder permission
```

Last question: will it work with PHP variables?
Like this one: `copy('skeleton.php', "../contents/posts/$post_name.php");`

Comment: Tell us about your file and directory **permissions**. Untag both php-7 and php-5.3; not relevant. Better elaborate on your OS, webserver and php SAPI. Explain what you mean with `... but it didn't identified "dir/$new_name.php"` (explain: as in more words and observations). And why is there no error_reporting in any of the examples?

Comment: File from htdocs/example.php to htdocs/newfile.php

Comment: Does the PHP Copy function have any kind of relationship with PHP ini?

Comment: @mario hey dear friend, please make answer as "Try changing server" because when I tried changing the server, the error solved.

Comment: Both you and me will be happy 

Comment: Possibly. But future visitors would just be as dumbfounded..

Comment: Then what do you thing?

Comment: Do I need to delete this question

Comment: That's the second option

Comment: Still there is another problem in my code.

Comment: When I tried using a variable as the new file name(
<?php  
$new_name = copy
(example.php, dir/$new_name.php); ?>
), The script didn't identified the variable and saved the file as real $new_name.php not as copy.php

Comment: This is not even a valid syntax. Also, you'd better check the ownership & permission of the folder.

Comment: @Raptor the copy issue is solved but now there is another issue. When I tried changing the new file's name as variable $newfilename.php, the server ignored $newfilename as variable. It just copied the file as $newfilename.php not used the text, which I stored inside variable $newfilename

Comment: There are a lot of code blocks you posted in your question, which one you're using now? You'd better update your question.